# Is there any documentation or guide for copying / pasting (cloning and restoring) Alfresco Community ECM?

Tags: postgresql, solr, alfresco, alfresco-share

Is there any documentation or guide for copying / pasting (cloning and restoring) an Alfresco Community - 5.1.0 installation with Alfresco, PostgreSQL and Solr4, from one Datacenter to another DC. with different IP addresses and hostnames.

We have 3 machines for this Alfresco installation:

alfrescodb:   Alfresco Community 5.1.0, PostgreSQL, Solr4 and NFS Server for sharing /opt/alfresco-community/alf_data. (Alfresco Documents and Solr Indexes).

alfresco1-2:  Alfresco Community 5.1.0 and NFS mounted /opt/alfresco-community/alf_data from alfrescodb.  These 2 nodes connect to the PgSQL database @ alfrescodb.

We need to copy/paste these 3 servers to a different Data Center, with different IP addresses, same hostnames.

We have performed a regular clone/restore of the VM using Hypervisor Tools (KVM).

Everything works fine EXCEPT the document tagging feature, which is broken.  The weird thing is that this feature works only @ alfrescodb Server and does not work at all at alfresco1-2 servers.

Any similar experience?  Any recommendation for this migration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is asking us to find an off-site resource (a *document or guide*), which is clearly indicated as being off-topic here in the site guidelines. It's also too vague and broad in scope (*Any similar experience? Any recommendations?*), which is also off-topic. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] pages in order to better understand what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here before your next post. Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest checking your Alfresco settings for the connection details of SOLR, my guess is your other machines are trying to connect to SOLR to search/update by IP not Hostname

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco Community Edition cannot be clustered, which is what it sounds like you are doing. You cannot have more than one Alfresco node pointing at the same database.

Aside from that, I agree with Gagravarr, the tagging system leverages solr. So unless you've done something to point all three machines to the same solr instance, this won't work even if you could get the clustering working.